# Aggregate data from named column of multiple rows/records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am updating a site that is essentially a competition where by each contestant is voted on by (n) number of judges, with each judge leaving feedback which is stored in the column 'feedback', in the  table 'recEntrantStatus'.

I need to be able to collect all feedback left for a given entrant, and collate this data before storing it in a variable in a stored procedure.

So for example to get all the feedback for a single entrant(eg all judge of 1 artist) I would use the following:

```
SELECT rndFeedback FROM recEntrantStatus WHERE roundId = 3 AND entrantId = @entrantId
```

However, I don't know how to work with this to collect ALL feedback from all judges for the current artist in the current round, and neatly collect this into 1 single declared variable that can then be used later in an insert.

A scenario to further clarify;

Its round 2 and 10 judges vote and leave feedback on a single entrant. I need to collect the feedback placed in each of the 10 records relating to each judge that votes on a specified entrant. This then needs to be aggregated into one declared variable in the existing Stored Process.

Each record would look something like this:

```
id | judgeId | entrantId | roundId | rndFeedback 
________________________________________________


1 | 5        | 22        | 2       | Awesome

1 | 8        | 22        | 2       | Really Nice Work

1 | 9        | 22        | 2       | The bass was a little heavy

1 | 10       | 22        | 2       | You Suck

1 | 11       | 22        | 2       | It was really good but lacking emotion

1 | 14       | 22        | 2       | You get my vote

1 | 15       | 22        | 2       | Nice Melody
```

So ultimately I would be looking to have collected all the feedback for entrantId = 22 as a single string of text which contains:

```
Awesome Really Nice Work The bass was a little heavy You Suck It was really good but lacking emotion You get my vote Nice Melody
```

P.s. rndFeedback is VARCHAR data type

Comment: See https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    id INT,
    judgeId INT,
    entrantId INT,
    roundId INT,
    rndFeedback VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES 
    (1, 5 , 22, 2, 'Awesome'),
    (1, 8 , 22, 2, 'Really Nice Work'),
    (1, 9 , 22, 2, 'The bass was a little heavy'),
    (1, 10, 22, 2, 'You Suck'),
    (1, 11, 22, 2, 'It was really good but lacking emotion'),
    (1, 14, 22, 2, 'You get my vote'),
    (1, 15, 22, 2, 'Nice Melody'),
    (1, 15, 23, 2, 'TEST'),
    (1, 15, 23, 2, NULL),
    (1, 15, 24, 2, NULL)

SELECT t1.entrantId, STUFF((
    SELECT ' ' + rndFeedback
    FROM @t t2
    WHERE t2.entrantId = t1.entrantId
        AND t2.roundId = 2
        AND t2.rndFeedback IS NOT NULL
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT entrantId
    FROM @t
    WHERE roundId = 2
        AND rndFeedback IS NOT NULL
) t1
```

output -

```
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22          Awesome Really Nice Work The bass was a little heavy You Suck It was really good but lacking emotion You get my vote Nice Melody
23          TEST
```

post - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691102/String-Aggregation-in-the-World-of-SQL-Server

Comment: Where should I add the WHERE clause for things such as 'WHERE roundId = 2 AND entrantId = 301 ??? Thanks.

Comment: It would be a known entrantId and round everytime. So I would send both of these to the SP as an input eg [@]roundId = 2, [@]entrantId = 301.

Comment: That appears to be partly working. The queury returns two identical rows. I have the following sql now: SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ' ' + rnd2Feedback
    FROM recEntrantStatus t2
    WHERE t2.entrantId = 401
        AND t2.roundId = 2
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT entrantId
    FROM recEntrantStatus
    --WHERE entrantId IN (...)
) t1

Comment: `WHERE t2.entrantId = t1.entrantId AND t2.roundId = 2`

Comment: That still returns a 2nd row with a null value.

Comment: That's working for me now thanks, would you mind helping me expand on this a little. I like how your offers the ability to grab the results for all entrants and return the feedback against the entrantId. Would you mind helping me work on how to make this part of an update statement? Essentially what I'm thinking off is grabbing all the feedback for each entrant, collating it -as it does now- but then rewriting(update) each feedback field with the collated data. This would have the result that all records for a given entrant would now all have the same complete set of collated feedback...

Comment: Thanks for the help. Ive asked a follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679895/perform-update-from-existing-select

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this.  I've include an example below, using this sample data:

Sample Data

```
/* Using a table variable allows everyone to 
 * share the same data.
 */
DECLARE @Sample TABLE
    (
        Id                INT,
        JudgeId            INT,
        EntrantId        INT,
        RoundId            INT,
        rndFeedBack        VARCHAR(50)
    )
;

/* Populated based on values supplied in OP.
 */
INSERT INTO @Sample
    (
        Id,
        JudgeId,
        EntrantId,
        RoundId,
        rndFeedBack
    )
VALUES
    (1, 5, 22, 2, 'Awesome'),
    (1, 8, 22, 2, 'Really Nice Work'),
    (1, 9, 22, 2, 'The bass was a little heavy'),
    (1, 10, 22, 2, 'You Suck'),
    (1, 11, 22, 2, 'It was really good but lacking emotion'),
    (1, 14, 22, 2, 'You get my vote'),
    (1, 15, 22, 2, 'Nice Melody'),
    (1, 15, 22, 2, NULL)
;
```

First you will need to declare a variable to hold the output.  Make sure it's big enough to hold the entire result or you will be presented with a trimmed value (trimming will not raise an error so it's easy to miss).

This technique requires you to initialize the variable, because the default value for a VARCHAR variable is NULL.  And NULL + 'any text' = NULL.  Our select statement below adds each returned value to the variable.

Finally you can use a [CASE Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181765.aspx) to conditionally build the return value.  In this example:

- NULLs are replaced with a blank string.
- rndFeedBack is prefixed with a comma if @Feeback already contains text.

Example

```
/* This will hold the concatenated value.
 * You must initialise this variable, to avoid NULL + text = NULL.
 */
DECLARE @Feedback VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT
    @Feedback = @Feedback +
        CASE
            WHEN rndFeedBack IS NULL    THEN ''
            WHEN LEN(@Feedback) > 1     THEN ',' + rndFeedBack
            ELSE rndFeedBack
        END
FROM
    @Sample
WHERE
    EntrantId = 22
    AND RoundId = 2
;


/* Check the returned value.
 */
SELECT
    @Feedback
;
```

**EDIT 1:** Added ISNULL to example code.

**EDIT 2:** Added CASE expression to the example code.  Added explanation of case to preceding paragraph.  Added NULL record to sample data.

Comment: This is just returning Null for some reason when performed against my existing table.

Comment: Does rndFeedBack allow NULLs?  If so NULL + 'text' = NULL would apply.  You fix this by wrapping [ISNULL()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms184325.aspx) around rndFeedback.  I've edited my answer to include this.

Comment: Ah ok. That works, however I now get a ',' for every null value in the final variable. Any idea(s) how to get around this at the SQL / SP level?

Comment: You can use a [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181765.aspx) expression to conditionally build you return value.  I'll edit the answer to include.

Comment: Sorry, I keep missing bits of info you already included in your answer. I'd better start reading it properly! ;-)

Comment: It's worth noting that your case statement doesn't account for feedback that consists of whitespace. Ive used the following: SELECT [@]Feedback =
    CASE 
      WHEN rndFeedback IS NULL THEN [@]Feedback
      WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(rndFeedback)) = '' THEN [@]Feedback
      WHEN rndFeedback IS NOT NULL THEN [@]Feedback + rndFeedback + '<br/>'
    END

Comment: do you have a moment to go into chat?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Ive asked a follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679895/perform-update-from-existing-select