# Perform UPDATE from existing SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table which contains data about a number of bands. Each band has numerous records in this table, which contain various bits of info and importantly feedback for them from some judges.

The table structure is essentially:

```
id | judgeId | entrantId | roundId | rndFeedback
```

---

The following SQL grabs all the feedback for each band and collates it into a single record. eg:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    id INT,
    judgeId INT,
    entrantId INT,
    roundId INT,
    rndFeedback VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES 
    (1, 5 , 22, 2, 'Awesome'),
    (1, 4 , 22, 2, 'Really Nice Work'),
    (1, 9 , 22, 2, 'The bass was a little heavy'),
    (1, 10, 22, 2, 'You Suck'),
    (1, 11, 22, 2, 'It was really good but lacking emotion'),
    (1, 14, 22, 2, 'You get my vote'),
    (1, 15, 22, 2, 'Nice Melody'),
    (1, 4, 23, 2, 'TEST'),
    (1, 15, 23, 2, NULL),
    (1, 4, 24, 2, NULL)

SELECT t1.entrantId, STUFF((
    SELECT ' ' + rndFeedback
    FROM @t t2
    WHERE t2.entrantId = t1.entrantId
        AND t2.roundId = 2
        AND t2.rndFeedback IS NOT NULL
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT entrantId
    FROM @t
    WHERE roundId = 2
        AND rndFeedback IS NOT NULL
) t1
```

output -

```
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22          Awesome Really Nice Work The bass was a little heavy You Suck It was really good but lacking emotion You get my vote Nice Melody
23          TEST
```

But, I now want to be able to take this feedback and update all the records for that band so that every record would contain the same collated feedback for that artist.

So for example the table would now look like:

```
    (1, 5 , 22, 2, 'Awesome Really Nice Work The bass was a little heavy You Suck It was really good but lacking emotion You get my vote Nice Melody'),
    (1, 4 , 22, 2, 'Awesome Really Nice Work The bass was a little heavy You Suck It was really good but lacking emotion You get my vote Nice Melody'),
    (1, 9 , 22, 2, 'Awesome Really Nice Work The bass was a little heavy You Suck It was really good but lacking emotion You get my vote Nice Melody'),
    (1, 10, 22, 2, 'Awesome Really Nice Work The bass was a little heavy You Suck It was really good but lacking emotion You get my vote Nice Melody'),
    (1, 11, 22, 2, 'Awesome Really Nice Work The bass was a little heavy You Suck It was really good but lacking emotion You get my vote Nice Melody'),
    (1, 14, 22, 2, 'Awesome Really Nice Work The bass was a little heavy You Suck It was really good but lacking emotion You get my vote Nice Melody'),
    (1, 15, 22, 2, 'Awesome Really Nice Work The bass was a little heavy You Suck It was really good but lacking emotion You get my vote Nice Melody'),
    (1, 4, 23, 2, 'TEST'),
    (1, 15, 23, 2, 'TEST'),
    (1, 4, 24, 2, NULL)
```

I've no idea how to go about doing this, as this is getting beyond my current level of t-sql knowledge.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe, but that's the reality of a real world scenario with a client wanting to change functionality years down the line without having the budget to have everything rewritten from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    id INT,
    judgeId INT,
    entrantId INT,
    roundId INT,
    rndFeedback VARCHAR(MAX) -- <<<
)

UPDATE t1
SET rndFeedback = NULLIF(STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(13) + rndFeedback
    FROM @t t2
    WHERE t2.entrantId = t1.entrantId
        AND t2.roundId = 2
        AND t2.rndFeedback IS NOT NULL
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''), '')
FROM @t t1
WHERE roundId = 2
```

Comment: Is there anyway with this to eliminate rows that are empty strings rather than null, as these are resulting in lots of '&#x20;' in the collated feedback. Also it'd be really good if I could add a '<br/>' after each piece of feedback, for later display purposes. This FOR XML stuff is new to me.

Comment: @Phill Healey please check the update and have a nice weekends

Comment: I just realised that the '&#x20;' are actually as a result of the empty string added in the SELECT line. However, it'd be good to be able to add a '<br/>' but only after a row with content. Is it possible to use a case statement or similar to do this?

Comment: Try to use `CHAR(13)`

Comment: Is it ok just just use CHAR(13) or is it better to use it with CHAR(10) ??

Comment: Any chance of a little explanation of what this bit does: .value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') ??? Thanks.

Comment: @Phill Healey `value` just tell "get value from the node"